# Webpack: HMR Update check failed Error: Manifest Request to ..... timed out at XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, mern

So I have this dev environment through work, and sometimes i can go 20 minutes or so without restarting the server, but most of the time its every little change. this is the error message that pops up
[image]

This is my webpack config

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var SaveHashes = require("assets-webpack-plugin");
var config = require("config");

//used to read in command line args
const args = require('yargs').argv;

var useConfig;

if (args.env && args.env.useConfig){
    useConfig = args.env.useConfig; //must match a key of a configuration
} else {
    useConfig = config.get("useConfig"); //must match a key of a configuration
}

//define config object
var configuration = config.get(useConfig); //the configuration object that has the key of useConfig

var router = ["regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./react/router.jsx"];

if (configuration.router) {
    router = configuration.router;
}

//define global webpack variables that go into definePlugin
var release = (args.env && args.env.BUILD_RELEASE === "true");

var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEV__: !release,
    __RELEASE__: release,
    __HMR__: true
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        router: router
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "javascripts"),
        filename: "router-bundle.js",
        publicPath: "http://<IP>:8080/javascripts/" // Relative to public folder
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(wav|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            { test: /\.pug$/, loader: "pug-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader" },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=32768" },
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: { presets: ["env", "react", "stage-2"] }
            },
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: { presets: ["env", "react", "stage-2"] }
            },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" }
        ]
    },
    node: { fs: "empty" },
    externals: {
        react: "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        uiplugin: "UIFactory",
        "./cptable": "var cptable",
        "./jszip": "jszip"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    plugins: [definePlugin]
};
```

I've tried different variations of publicPath value also other different configs with no avail!

webpack version comes up 3.9.1

A faster development process where I don't have to restart the HMR every time I save a file would be nice!

Comment: Similar issue here, did you solved it?